# strcmp can't convert char* to const char* in a prefix evaluation code (c++)

Tags: c++, char, prefix, const-char

I'm writing a code to evaluate a prefix expression. The values of the expression are separated by spaces. So if the input is "+ * 87 89 666", I should get 8409 as the answer. The concept of my code is to store the values to an array and then evaluate them value by value. Right now I'm stuck at the switch part because the compiler says invalid conversion from char to const char*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

char n[99999][6]={};

int evaluatePrefix(int l)
{
    stack<int> Stack;

    for (int j = l; j >= 0; j--) {
        string x=n[j];
        if (n[j][0]!='+' || n[j][0]!='-' || n[j][0]!='*' || n[j][0]!='/'){
            stringstream ss;
            int a;
            ss<<x;
            ss>>a;
            Stack.push(a);
        }
        else {
            int o1 = Stack.top();
            Stack.pop();
            int o2 = Stack.top();
            Stack.pop();
            if (strcmp(n[j], '+')==0){
                Stack.push(o1 + o2);
            }
            else if (strcmp(x, '-')==0){
                Stack.push(o1 - o2);
            }
            else if (strcmp(x, '*')==0){
                Stack.push(o1 * o2);
            }
            else if (strcmp(x, '/')==0){
                Stack.push(o1 / o2);
            }
        }
    }

    return Stack.top();
}

int main()
{
    char e[99999], w[99999];
    int i=0;
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",e);
    char *token = strtok(e, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(n[i], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which C++ textbook taught you to use `bits/stdc++.h`? There is no such standard header file in C++, it's a compiler-specific non-standard header. Whichever C++ textbook this came from should be thrown away and replaced [with a better C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/). Looks like the same textbook also doesn't correctly explain why declaring large arrays in function is also undesirable, for technical reasons. If this is something your teacher or instructor showed you -- you have an incompetent instructor, unfortunately.

Comment: I recommend watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk or have your instructor watch it to understand why you need a better/newer c++ textbook.

Comment: Next problem: `if (n[j][0] != ‘+’ || n[j][0] != ‘-‘)` is always true.

Comment: Why mix string streams and char arrays? Why not use strings everywhere?

Comment: see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
if (strcmp(n[j], '+')==0)
```

`n[j]` decays into a `char*`, but `'+'` is a single `char`, not a `char*`. `strcmp` needs two char pointers.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

So, you should use:

```
if (strcmp(n[j], "+")==0)
```

Comment: Also pay attention to the good comments of @SamVarshavchik , even though they're not the immediate cause of the compile error